SQL (Google Big Query) - I need a value that repeats on every row in a specific condition
I'm a SQL-novice and working in Google Big Query...
I have a table like this, a manager have some employees and the employees are males or females.



Manager_
Employee_
Gender___




John__
Henry__
Male


John__
Sam___
Male


John__
Joe___
Male


John__
Jack__
Male


Adam__
Donald
Male


Adam__
George
Male


Adam__
Samantha
Female


Adam__
Tim
Male


Mary__
Celine
Female


Mary__
Annie
Female


Mary__
Emmy
Female


Mary__
Jenny
Female



I want something like this, a column tells that the managers group is mixed or just contain males or females, like the table below:



Manager_
Employee_
Gender___
Variation




John__
Henry__
Male
Only_male


John__
Sam___
Male
Only_male


John__
Joe___
Male
Only_male


John__
Jack__
Male
Only_male


Adam__
Donald
Male
Mixed


Adam__
George
Male
Mixed


Adam__
Samantha
Female
Mixed


Adam__
Tim
Male
Mixed


Mary__
Celine
Female
Only_female


Mary__
Annie
Female
Only_female


Mary__
Emmy
Female
Only_female


Mary__
Jenny
Female
Only_female



The value in the "variation" column must be repeated on every row, in this case where Adam is manager.
Or some other opportunity to filter a group of mixed genders?
I don't know what to try... :( Sorry!

We can use COUNT() as window function here:
SELECT
    Manager,
    Employee,
    Gender,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN Gender = 'Male' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Manager) =
              COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Manager)
         THEN 'Only_male'
         WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN Gender = 'Female' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Manager) =
              COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Manager)
         THEN 'Only_female'
         ELSE 'Mixed' END AS Variation
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Manager;


Slightly simplier WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN Gender = 'Male' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Manager) = 0 THEN 'only_female'.

@jarlh Actually, I think that BigQuery supports boolean expressions, so your improvement might be simplified to: WHEN SUM(Gender = 'Male') OVER (PARTITION BY Manager) = 0
